# Is it possible to switch between items copied in the clipboard?

Tags: clipboard, copy, gnome-shell

I'm using Clipboard Indicator listed here: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/779/clipboard-indicator/

This allows me to keep multiple items in the clipboard and select or use them without having to copy them over and over.

Is it possible via this tool or any other, that I could switch between those items in the clipboard memory via a keyboard shortcut or a key?

For e.g., suppose I have the following items in the clipboard history:

- StackOverflow <--
- SuperUser
- ServerFault

The position of the arrow shows the item that will be pasted according to the current clipboard memory.

Is it possible to somehow move this arrow down with a keyboard only, so that it comes down to:

- StackOverflow
- SuperUser  <--
- ServerFault

and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CopyQ](https://hluk.github.io/CopyQ/) - the most feature-heavy clipboard manager for Linux, currently - for instance:

1. Launch the app.
2. Go to `File` -> `Preferences...` -> `Shortcuts`
3. Set global shortcuts to chosen key combination for `Copy next item` and `Copy previous item`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @Destroy666